# Can I position multiple panes in a column?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I recently learned about the Style Inspector feature of MS Word, and it seems so useful that I'd like to have it on display all the time. Like the Navigation Pane, it supports being anchored to the left side of the window or detached as a child window. But there's no obvious way to anchor both in the same column, one below the other. This would be preferable to having them displayed side-by-side, because neither takes up a great deal of vertical space and there is no purpose to the large grey area underneath. If you move one of the two panes around, MS Office will swap the horizontal order of the panes or detach them as child windows, but it will not tile them vertically. Is there some way to make it do this?

A possible workaround is this:

- detach each pane as a child window
- take the pane you want at the bottom, and carefully position it at the bottom-left corner of the document window *without* moving it so close to the window's edge that it becomes anchored at the side
- take the other pane and anchor it.

The result is that the second pane is anchored at the side, while the first pane is above it at the bottom, giving a kind of ersatz tiling. There are two drawbacks to this approach:

- If you anchor the Navigation pane and have the Style Inspector floating on top of it, then for views in which the Navigation Pane has a lot of content, the bottom of that content will be obscured by the Style Inspector child window.
- When Word doesn't have the focus, it doesn't display its child windows. The result is that when Word gains and loses the focus, the "pane" that isn't anchored will blink in and out of view, which is distracting.